# simulate as3 crossdomain behavior in localhost

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am writing an action script 3.0 client that has to communicate with a remote server. In localhost environment everything works fine, but if I test the client in the real internet environment there is no connection.

My guess is that it has to do with the cross domain policy file, but calling

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://"+targetIP);
```

does not send the `<policy file request\>` message to the server on the default 843 port, or any port for that matter. I think it might be because flash recognises that the address is local and omits the request. But I need to receive it to be able to implement the answer on the server. Otherwise I'd be coding blindly.

Is there a way to force the flash client to behave as if it was in a different domain while still being in localhost so I can troubleshoot this issue without involving a remote host? I don't have many resources in that regard.

Comment: Sure... you could add an entry to your hosts file... this will be in different location, depending on the OS you're using.

Comment: Here is how I solved this issue. I published the client with a stand alone projector(.exe). If you run the client wrapped in the exe it will behave the way a normal remote client would. Hope other people read this and save their time!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the client on 'localhost', and load the policy file from '127.0.0.1'.
They should be seen as different 'domains'.